# Akka http route with scala future

Tags: scala, future, akka-http

Here is the situation

```
// validateRoute act like a directive which validate a route before proceeding further
override def validateRoute(route: Route)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Route = {
  extractRequest { request =>
    decodeRequest {
      entity(as[String]) { content =>
        (headerValueByName("header1") & headerValueByName("header2")) {
          case (header1, header2) => {
            // dom some
            // validate() returns a Future[Either[Error, Boolean]]
            validate().map {
              result => {
                result match {
                  case Right(_) => route
                  case Left(ex) => complete(StatusCodes.Unauthorized -> ex.getMessage)
                }
              }
            }
          } // I get a error here saying It expect route whereas it is Future[Route]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the above mentioned error, also I can not change the return type of validate () , is there a way to fix this issue. I need a way to return route instead of Future[Route]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've a `handleRejections` directive registered, you can use the `onSuccess` directive on `Future`:

```
onSuccess(validate()) {
  case Right(_) => route
  case Left(ex) => complete(StatusCodes.Unauthorized -> ex.getMessage)
}
```

Else you can use `onComplete` directive and you'll have to match `Success` and `Failure`

Answer (score -1):

If you HAVE to return route instead of Future[Route], you can try using

```
Await.result(validate(), Duration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) //substitute your choice of duration
```

this will block till validate returns.

So the full solution will look like,

```
// validateRoute act like a directive which validate a route before proceeding further
override def validateRoute(route: Route)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Route = {
  extractRequest { request =>
    decodeRequest {
      entity(as[String]) { content =>
        (headerValueByName("header1") & headerValueByName("header2")) {
          case (header1, header2) => {
            // dom some
            // validate() returns a Future[Either[Error, Boolean]]
            Await.result(validate(),Duration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ) match 
                {
                  case Right(_) => route
                  case Left(ex) => complete(StatusCodes.Unauthorized -> ex.getMessage)
                }
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```